# Java classpath issue when I specify the directory in the command

Tags: java, git, servlets

When I try running my Java application, it cannot find the main class in the directory I specify.

My application is in this directory:

`C:\Users\Cristian\git\tranquil-crag-4851`

My main class is in this directory:

`C:\Users\Cristian\git\tranquil-crag-4851\target\classes\com\example`

My main class is called

`Main.class`

When I run this command

`java -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* com.example.Main`

from directory

`C:\Users\Cristian\git\tranquil-crag-4851\`

the result I get is:

**Could not find the main class in com.example.Main**

My CLASSPATH variable is set to `JAVA_HOME\lib`. Can somebody explain to me how to solve this?

Comment: Do you have a package statement at the top of your main class?

Comment: What is the package statement in the `Main` class?

Comment: I have this "package com.example;"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The delimiter `:` works on Unix. You should use `;` on Windows instead. 
I am not sure that forward slashes work on Windows in this context. Try to use back slashes instead, i.e.

`java -cp target\classes;target\dependency\* com.example.Main`

If you are using java 1.6 or higher this should work. I mean that `*` was not supported by previous versions of java.

If something does not work, check the path. 
Go to the directory where you are running your application, type

```
dir target\classes
dir target\dependency\
```

and see that the output of these commands is as expected.

Comment: Thanks is too much. Marking answer as correct and up-voting is enough. :)